# UIImage Animation Reverting Back To Original Position

Tags: animation, uiimage

Im pretty new to coding but I'm starting to get the hang of the basics.

**how to make an image stay in its new position after an animation?**

*Example*:
I'm giving an animating object a random position, however, the animation causes the object not to animate at the random position, but instead animate at the position it was given in the view controller. This also happens when I animate a completly different object.

### Code I used:

```
int Random1x;
int Random1y;

IBOutlet UIButton *Start;
IBOutlet UIImageview *Object2;

-(void)ObjectMoving;
-(void)Object2Animate;



-(IBAction)Start:(id)sender{

[self ObjectMoving];
[self Object2Animate];

}



-(void)Object2Animate {
Object2.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:   
[UIImage  imageNamed:@"2.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed: @"3.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed: @"4.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed: @"1.png"], nil];

Object2.animationDuration = .5
[Object2 setanimationRepeatCount: 0]
[Object2 startAnimating];
}

-(void)ObjectMoving {

Random1y = arc4random() % 466;
Random1y = Random1y + 60;
Random1x = arc4random() % 288;

Object2.center = CGPointMake(Random1x, Random1y);
}
```

I'd greatly appreciate help, thank you!

Comment: Please mention your code in Question

Comment: add the code where u set the random animation position  This code will just animate through the images in the array

Comment: I copied the code I currently have into the question above. What should I do to it?

Comment: Can you also post the code where you are defining your variables

Comment: I have other variables also but these are the only ones affecting the animation portion which is what is causing the problem of the random placement. If I take out the animation the Object will place in a random spot like it is suppose to. When the animation is in the object will go to the random spot for about half a second and then it will go to the spot that it orginally started in, in the view controller

Comment: I tested your code and the only way i was able to set the center is turning of auto layout.  Are you using auto layout in you storyboard?

Comment: I'm not sure, how would I find out it out? If I am how would I turn it off? Thank you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to your story board file and click on the View Controller and then file inspector you will see a box for Auto Layout

[image]

Post back if that worked.

If you do need to use auto layout then you would have to figure out a different way of moving the image.